# JBoss Messaging disable persistence

Tags: jboss, persistence, jms, jboss-messaging

I have few questions
1. How I can disable persistence for JBoss Messaging?
2. Is there any way to check that persistence was successfully disabled? (MBean or something else)
3. Maybe anybody knows tricks which will help me to disable persistence for specified queue not for all JBoss Messaging

Could you help me please :)

Enterprise Platform 4.3.0GA_CP06

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, the JMS persistence configuration is placed in path `server/default/deploy/jms/<db>-xxx-service.xml`, to disable persistence, you can follow the file `docs/examples/jms/null-persistence-service.xml`.

For Q2, I think it depend on your current persistence config, or you can try 1) produce message, 2) restart jboss, 3) inspect available messages.

Hope it helps.